# How RDDs are created in Structured streaming in spark?

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

How RDDs are created in Structured streaming in Spark? In DStream, we have for every batch, does it create as soon as Data is available or trigger happens? How does it physically distributes RDDs across executors?

Comment: Is this about Spark Structured Streaming (Dataset API) or Spark Streaming (DStream API)?

Answer (score -1):

Internally, a DStream is represented as a sequence of RDDs,
which is Spark’s abstraction of an immutable, distributed dataset. Each RDD in a DStream contains data from a certain interval

IN the word count example:-

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ // not necessary since Spark 1.3
// Count each word in each batch
val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)

// Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
wordCounts.print()
```

So, an RDD is created on the driver for the blocks created during the batchInterval. The blocks generated during the batchInterval are partitions of the RDD. Each partition is a task in spark. blockInterval== batchinterval would mean that a single partition is created and probably it is processed locally.

DStreams are executed lazily by the output operations, just like RDDs are lazily executed by RDD actions.

DStream will execute as soon as the trigger happens, if your time interval is 2 seconds, job will trigger for each and every 2 seconds, basically the triggering point is not the data availability it is batch duration, if the data present at the time the DStream contains the data otherwise it will be empty.

DStream is actually a sequence of RDD from the code of DStream:-

```
  // RDDs generated, marked as private[streaming] so that testsuites can access it
  @transient
  private[streaming] var generatedRDDs = new HashMap[Time, RDD[T]]()
```

number of executors generated depends upon partition as well as configuration provided.

There are normally two types of allocation in the configuration static allocation and dynamic allocation.
you can read about them here:-

http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/understanding-resource-allocation-configurations-spark-application/

Comment: How does it create RDD with structured streaming, I mean how many executors are created and how partitions are distributed?